# Time profiler between a certain range of time?

Tags: xcode, profiling, instruments

I wonder how can I setup the time profiler instrument to show me the calls that are done between a period of time. I don't want it to show me all the calls of running time.
Is this possible?

I've been trying with flags but no see anything to change.

Basically I want to focus on a certain peak.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Option-drag on the timeline in instruments to just include results from that time range. Simple as that, really.

Comment: This just zoomed in on Xcode 7.3, Control drag zoomed back out. However,  Command drag did work.

Comment: Actually, in 7.3, I don't think *any* modifier key is needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way (that I'm aware of anyway) to trigger arbitrary flags in Instruments from user code. I've come up with a couple of alternatives.

The simplest one I've found is to put a call to `sleep(1)` right before and right after the stuff I want to look at, this means that I can easily identify a period of total idle right before and after the zone of interest.  Crude, but effective.

The other alternative is that you can use Instruments' custom instrument mechanism to instrument certain calls.  This can, similarly, give you other items on the timeline that you can use for reference. These can be challenging to create and get just right, so most often I just use the cruder method described above.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Not sure when this changed, but in Xcode 11, Option-dragging only performs a zoom. It doesn't change the range of reported data. Cmd-dragging does nothing. The key is to just drag across the range, but do it in the content region of the Time Profiler plot area - NOT the "time bar" at the top.